# How to keep the information from which table a user has selected an item?

Tags: hibernate, database-design

Consider the following scenario: I am having `Item` that can be listed in `ItemList` or be available in an `ItemSet`. Something like this:

```
@Entity
class Item {

   @Id Long id;
}

@Entity
class ItemList {

   @Id Long id;
   @OneToMany Collection<Item> items;
}

@Entity
class ItemSet {

   @NotNull
   @OneToOne Item importantItem; // One of them must not be null

   @OneToOne Item second;
   @OneToOne Item third;

   @NotNull Date date;
}
```

Now, the problem that I am having is that I want to be able to have a *voting* among users who are allowed to vote one item from `ItemList` *or* **one entire** `ItemSet`.

I would like to have a table where I can see what a user has voted for such that other users can see from which category others have been voting for (`ItemList` or `ItemSet` category). I could do something like this:

```
@Entity
class Vote {
    @OneToOne Item item;
    @NotNull Date date
    VoteType type;
}

enum VoteType {
    ITEM_LIST_VOTE,
    ITEM_SET_VOTE
}
```

But I don't really like that because such a `Vote` isn't really tied to anything here.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish a voting system like this? I am not sure if I should go for such known types (`VoteType`).

One more thing to consider is that `ItemSet` has a date that means one can only vote for the `ItemSet` on that specified day.

Comment: The question is not clear , show us your table design.

Comment: @MohsenHeydari Hi! What is not clear? Up there is my table design.

Comment: It seams some thing is not right here, or i can not understand it. lets see. Can an item be part of multiple ItemsLists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
I will suggest having a parent table called `Vote-able` for any element that can be voted. This `Vote-able` table will have zero-or-one relation to all of these tables (Item-Set and Item-list for now).
A record in documentary table will show one and only one record in one of other tables.
`Vote-able` table will have a type field showing its related record type. 
Having FK of this `Vote-able`inside vote table will solve the problem.
Consider vote-able entity as an abstract class.

Comment: This looks heavy! Not sure if I'm really going to go with this solution but it would work. In the end I'll have to look at the pros and cons of the known-types solution and this one.